# Importing a git repo from one vsts team project to another team project using vsts rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Want to initiate a VSTS git repo import from project A to Project B. Following script is written to createthe import request via REST API. It is giving bad request 400 as described below. Any clues?

```
param(
    <parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    [string] $token,
    <parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    [string] $collectionUri,
    <parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    [string] $TargetTeamProject,
    <parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    [string] $TargetGitRepoName,
    <parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    [string] $SourceGitRepoUrl
)
$User=""

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$token)));
$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)};
$Uri = $collectionUri + $TargetTeamProject + '/_apis/git/repositories/' + $TargetGitRepoName + '/importRequests?api-version=4.1-preview.1'
$ImportRequestData = '{"parameters": {"gitSource": {"url": "' + $SourceGitRepoUrl + '"}}}'
write-host 'calling:' $Uri
write-host 'with data:' $ImportRequestData
$ImportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $ImportRequestData -Headers $header
$ImportResponse
```

Called it with

```
.\CreateImportRequest.ps1 -token '*************************************' -collectionUri 'https://myvsts.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/' -TargetTeamProject 'HasiTempJava' -TargetGitRepoName 'impfromhasiJava' -SourceGitRepoUrl 'https://myvsts.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/HasiJava'
```

When passed existing empty repo it throws bad request exception

```
    Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    At C:\Users\chamindac\Desktop\CreateImportRequest.ps1:33 char:19
    + ... tResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/j ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand</parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)>
    When a new repo name used it is giving below error which is correct I believe since url refers to a non existing repo

<parameter(mandatory=$true)><parameter(mandatory=$true)><parameter(mandatory=$true)><parameter(mandatory=$true)><parameter(mandatory=$true) class="">Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier impfromhasiJavaNew does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are 
attempting.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitRepositoryNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitRepositoryNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At C:\Users\chamindac\Desktop\CreateImportRequest.ps1:33 char:19
+ ... tResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/j ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand </parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)></parameter(mandatory=$true)>
As per documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/import%20requests/create) only required parameter is the source git repo url. Is there any additional parameter requirements?
```

Post url used

```
https://myvsts.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/HasiTempJava/_apis/git/repositories/impfromhasiJava/importRequests?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Request Body

```
{"parameters": {"gitSource": {"url": "https://myvsts.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/HasiJava"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add the source repo (from project A) as an External Git Endpoint for the target project (project B)**, and then provide the argument **`serviceEndpointId`** for [create import requests REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/import%20requests/create#examples).
Detail steps ad below:

1. Create External Git Endpoint in target project

   In project B -> Services Hub (https://account.visualstudio.com/projectB/_admin/_services) -> New Service Endpoint -> External Git -> add source repo from project A as the server URL (https://account.visualstudio.com/projectA/_git/sourcerepo) -> OK.

   [image]
2. Get the endpoint id

   Use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get) as below:

   ```
   GET https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/GitTest/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/?api-version=4.1-preview.1
   ```

   Then get the endpoint id from the response (assume it's `c534772b-bf52-442f-abd0-544d6bf76ed9`).
3. import git repo to the target porject

   Then import the source repo from project A to project B:

   ```
   POST https://account.visualstudio.com/projectB/_apis/git/repositories/targetrepo/importRequests?api-version=4.1-preview.1
   ```

   application/json:

   ```
   {
     "parameters": {
       "gitSource": {
         "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/projectA/_git/sourcerepo"
       },
       "serviceEndpointId": "c534772b-bf52-442f-abd0-544d6bf76ed9"
     }
   }
   ```

More details, you can refer the blog [Import a Git Project with REST API between VSTS Team Projects](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/08/import-a-git-project-with-rest-api-between-vsts-team-projects/).